# How to render a component when clicking another component? React

Tags: reactjs

I have this one component which renders another component , please note the else if in the render

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fieldId: "",
            rating: -1,
            description: "",
            showModal: false
        };
        console.log(props) //week number, beginning with 0
        this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    }
.
.

.    
showModal() {
        this.setState({
            showModal: true
        })
        console.log("clicked show modal")
    }
.
.
.
.
.
render() {
        var weekId = this.props.weekId;
        if (weekId < this.props.livedWeeks) {
            return <div id={weekId} className="cube-lived"></div>
        } else if (weekId == this.props.currentWeek) { //whenever i click the component right below (cube - green), i want to render, <CalendarFieldModal />
            return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className="cube green" onClick={this.showModal}> 
                { this.state.showModal ? <CalendarFieldModal /> : null}

            </div>
        } else {
            return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className="cube white" onClick={this.showModal}> </div>
        }


    }
```

This is the component to that the else if element is supposed to render on click

```
    import React from 'react'
import './CalendarFieldModal.css'
class CalendarFieldModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="modal-main">
                    <p>hi</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CalendarFieldModal;
```

this is its css

```
 p{
    font-size: 10000px;
    color: blue;
}
```

But whenever I click i cant see anything appearing, so im wondering whats the issue, why is it not rendering anything? As for example the simple

that I want to render as a test to see if it works.

EDIT:

I figured that whenever I click the component for the first time, the showModal state is logged in the console as false, and it wont show up as true until the second click. But anyway it still wont render the other element even with double click, so still stuck there

Comment: earlier condition (weeks, not state related) blocks the rest

Comment: @xadm any idea of where to place that <CalendarFieldModal /> So it renders on click then? Im not quite sure of what to do now...

Comment: start without other conditions, only middle variant (div + conditional)

Comment: @xadm im not sure what you mean to be honest, i tried to leave my entire render like this removing all the conditions ```return <div id={weekId} title={weekId} className="cube green" onClick={this.showModal}> 
                 { this.state.showModal ? <CalendarFieldModal /> : null}
            </div>``` , but it still wont render anything

Comment: should work, console.log state in render ... prepare demo on codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually working, it's just because your css font size in CalendarFieldModal is too large to render in a proper position, and the reason that every time you click the component, the showModal State is still false, is because `setState` is asynchronous, so `console.log` below `setState` may execute before the state is actually updated, so if you want to log the state in the console after it's actually updated, instead you can use

```
this.setState({
       showModal: true
   }, () => console.log(this.state.showModal))
```

you can see the difference between after state updating and before state updating in the console.

[image: Edit keen-bardeen-pin6n]